# How do I parse and load a JSON file when an app starts?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I have this class

```dart
class Notes {
  Map _notes = {};
  Map get notes => _notes;

  // Fetch notes from a json file
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/sample.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    _notes = data;
  }
}
```

In the `Build()` function, before `return Scaffold()` I call

```dart
  // load notes when app starts
    var myNotes = Notes();
    myNotes.readJson();
    print(myNotes.notes);
```

I'm confused about what's happening. I assume when I call `myNotes.readJson()`

1. the JSON file is loaded and assigned to the `response` String,
2. decoded and assigned to the `data` variable, and then
3. assigned to `_notes`.

If I insert a `print(_notes)` statement in `readJson()`, I see what I would expect--the contents of my JSON file.

At this point, I assume `print(myNotes.notes)` (from `main()`) should have the same content, which I can ultimately work with in `Build()`. But the statement produces an empty map.

I am confused about what's happening, where my thinking is incorrect, and unsure how to write the code so the JSON file will be loaded and available for decoding when the app starts.

P.S. Just in case this looks like a weird way to work with a local file, eventually the program will be loading a file that's not local.

Comment: I believe it's because readJson() is a future and it has not had time to finish its processing when you call  myNotes.readJson()... Call "await myNotes.readJson()" and add async to the function containing this call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use future builder for asynchronous methods:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: notes.readJson(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final notes = snapshot.data as Map;
        return Text(notes.length.toString()); //handle your UI here
      } else {
        return const Text('No data available');
      }
    },
  )
```

and make sure to change the return type to map in readJson():

```
Future<Map> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/sample.json');
    _notes = await json.decode(response);
    return _notes;
  }
```